# Failure upgrading a rooted stock Nexus One to Android 2.2.1

Tags: 2.2-froyo, ota-update, root-access

I have a root Nexus one, that at one point ran a custom ROM, but now has the stock Android 2.2 release. I just got an update to 2.2.1, and it fails with:

```
Build : RA-nexus-v1.5.3
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Verifying update package...
E:No signature (188 files)
E:Verification failed
Installation aborted.
```

What is the problem? Why does it say 1.5.3 in the build?

Answer (score 1):

Installing the stock Android 2.2 FRF91 or newer unroots the phone. I had this same problem.

You can downgrade and root using the directions here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=717870

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing a stock image from ROM manager and then upgrading from there?  Just to make certain that you are using a clean stock image.

Are you wanting to keep root?  Any OTA updates might remove your root (I don't have a N1, so I don't know how the 2.2.1 update will affect your root status).

Comment: I don't need to keep root. When I installed 2.2 I definitely installed a stock image manually.